# Golang GAE - Federated Login examples

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, openid, go, federated-identity

I'm trying to implement Federated Login using Google App Engine Go SDK, but the only examples I can find on the subject are about [how to do this in Python and Java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid). I understand that I need to call [this function](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/reference#LoginURLFederated) to get the URL, but I'm not sure about the parameters to pass. Can someone provide examples of Federated Login in GAE Golang for a few major platforms (Facebook, Twitter, etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook and Twitter don't use OpenID for authentication.

Facebook uses [OAuth 2](http://oauth.net/2/) - You'll need to use [goauth2](http://code.google.com/p/goauth2/) to authenticate.

Twitter uses: [OAuth](http://oauth.net/). You'll need to use [goauth](http://code.google.com/p/goauth2/) to authenticate.

That said if you are still wanting to use Federated Login for providers like Yahoo, Google, MySpace it would look like this:

```golang
c := appengine.NewContext(r)

// url is the OpenID url other possiblities include:
//   - yahoo.com
//   - myspace.com
//   - aol.com
//   - flickr.com/USERNAME

url := "gmail.com"

// redirectURL is where you want the User to be redirected to after login.

redirectURL := "/callback"
loginUrl, err := user.LoginURLFederated(c, redirectURL, url)

// Then redirect the user to the url.

http.Redirect(w, r, loginUrl, http.StatusFound)
```

For Facebook and Twitter authentication you might look at the [go.auth](https://github.com/bradrydzewski/go.auth) package. It might not work with App Engine but it might give you some clues.

I'm also working on a solution to this problem in the [HAL/auth](https://github.com/scotch/hal/tree/master/auth) package, but as of now it's incomplete. Here's how HAL handles [app engine openid](https://github.com/scotch/hal/blob/master/auth/appengine_openid/appengine_openid.go).